# Change label position while app is in production

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase

Is there a way to change the position of a label or any other component while the IOS application written in swift is in production using some google related service or maybe firebase?

I have seen a tutorial somewhere where simple data like text or label position can be changed while the app is in production, I can't seem to recall it.

Comment: You want the changes to reflect in end user device without sending to appstore right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given how you've tagged your question, I assume you're talking about [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/). This allows you to define variables that you use in your application code, and that you can then modify from the Firebase console.

If you'd define the label position as such a Remote Config variable, you could update them from the server without having to ship an update. You can even target specific values to specific groups of user.

Comment: this is bad really. i mean,what if user dont have internet connection.

Comment: your right @GeneCode, in my case I am not doing it to actually change the position of the label as such, just changing some text that's not critical to the running of the application without making a network call, let me know if you have better ways of doing it.

Comment: @GeneCode There is a default value for each variable that is included in the binary.